# MongoDB find vs findOne - find not working

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to pull up all the books that belong to a certain user. I'm able to get the info I need using findOne but only for one document. It doesn't show all the documents (books) that belong to the user. Is there something I'm missing? Why does find not work in this situation but findOne does?

authActions.js

```
export const getBooks = (user) => dispatch => {

    axios
        .get("/api/users/wishlist", {
            params: {
                id: user
            }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            const data = response.data;
            console.log(data)
        })

        .catch(() =>{
            console.log("Error!")
        })
    };
```

books.js

```
router.get("/wishlist", (req, res) => {
    const db = mongoUtil.getDb();

//if I change findOne to find it doesn't work
    db.db("mern-auth-2").collection("savedbooks").findOne({id:req.body.id})

    .then(booksarray => res.json(booksarray))
});
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting when using `find`?

Comment: I get an internal server error. That doesn't work. I think it's because I'm looking for the param id. It's not an objectId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Mongoose documentation for [find](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) shows a sample callback like this:

```
MyModel.find({ name: 'john', age: { $gte: 18 }}, function (err, docs) {});
```

Try passing

```
(err, booksarray) => res.json(booksarray)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why but that didn't work as well. Here is how I wrote it:

router.get("/wishlist", (req, res) => {
    const db = mongoUtil.getDb();

    db.db("mern-auth-2").collection("savedbooks").find({id:req.body.id}, function(err, booksarray));

    (err, booksarray) => res.json(booksarray)
    // .then(booksarray => res.json(booksarray))
});

Comment: "did't work" meaning error or empty response?

Comment: A Mongoose find expects a callback that takes 2 arguments.  The MongoDB node driver [find](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#find) returns a [cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html)

Comment: Correct, empty response, though I know there are documents that should be returned. I'll look into what a cursor is. Would the console.log(data) in the AuthActions file not log the cursor?

Comment: It will only see the json from booksarray.  If the callback should be `(err, docs) => {}` , the first argument is the error message  and should be empty if the find succeeds.