# MongoDB - find returns empty where findOne does not

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm tearing my hair out, trying to write a simple query in MongoDB Application Services, which I believe uses Mongoose in Node.js.

I have a simple collection with `Users`, and I'm trying to `find` a set of users.

In testing, this prints a single user, as expected:

```
exports = async function(){
  db = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("2021_10_DB");
  const user_col = db.collection("Users");
  alarmingSubjs = await user_col.findOne();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(alarmingSubjs));
  return "Done";
}
```

```
====== log ======
> ran at 1672322424787
> took 691.479418ms
> logs: 
{"_id":"61807c0fd8c5df7ff5d09571",...}     <----- prints entire document for a single user
> result: 
"Done"
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('"Done"')
```

but, switching `findOne` to `find` prints no users, which is not expected. (ref [db.collection.find()](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) and [querying documents](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-documents/))

```
exports = async function(){
  db = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("2021_10_DB");
  const user_col = db.collection("Users");
  alarmingSubjs = await user_col.find();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(alarmingSubjs));
  return "Done";
}
```

```
====== log ======
> ran at 1672322583386
> took 443.279884ms
> logs: 
{}                         <------ no documents
> result: 
"Done"
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('"Done"')
```

I tried:

- removing `async` and `await`, this makes both `find` and `findOne` return an empty object
- embedding a function in `find`, which is not discussed in the documentation that I found, but is discussed in a few stack overflow questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524953/mongodb-find-vs-findone-find-not-working)), doing this:

```
// tried this
db.collection("Users").find({}, (err, user) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
});

//and this
db.collection("Users").find({}, (err, user) => {
  console.log(user);
});
```

both result in

```
> ran at 1672323629660
> took 273.490161ms
> result: 
"Done"
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('"Done"')
```

- I tried using `runCommand` but I get `TypeError: 'runCommand' is not a function`

Comment: I'm thinking of joining one of those no-technology communes so I can be as far away from javascript as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not look like Mongoose, it looks like the regular Node.js Mongo driver.

Which would return a cursor object from `find()`, as shown in the documentation [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.13/classes/Collection.html#find).

Please try

```js
alarmingSubjs = await user_col.find().toArray();
```

Which would enumerate the cursor and return an array.

Comment: I know I tried that too, but I guess my unfamiliarity with js logging tripped me up. Thanks a bunch